# LINQ - throw system.OutOfMemoryException issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, memory

In my .net application, I have used LINQ-to-SQL to get some data from the database. The volume of data is not big at all (10 rows of data). But I constantly caught the "system.outofmemoryException" in my function even thought there is still spare memory in the server. Interestingly, I can still get the data with a ADO function from other pages.

The problem will be fixed once application pool restarts. From time to time, issue happen again. Do you have any clue how I should debug this scenario?

Note: I have used "using" block for all datacontext connection. Literally, All datacontext would be disposed after use.

Below is the code. It is simple.

```
using (StoreDataContext db = new StoreDataContext(conn)) 
{
     var list = from category in db.ProductCategories 
                select category;

     ddlCategory.DataSource = list.Distinct().ToList();
     ddlCategory.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
     ddlCategory.DataValueField = "CategoryName";
     ddlCategory.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You have memory leaks in your application , you need to test your application through a good memory profiler

Comment: I would suggest you post your Linq code; it seems that either your rows are *huge* or there's something wrong with the Linq query that's causing it to pull back too much data.

Comment: Could you show us your linq query and model of classes you used in this query? it seems that you take circullar navigation properties

Comment: Why are you using `Distinct`? It implies that you're not selecting from master table.

Comment: Do you need all columns?? if not use **select new{ID=category.categoryID,Name=category.categoryName}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would you use memory profiling tool such as [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [RedGate's Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler&gclid=CP-y66HAyLECFbMJtAodKmgAxQ) (their are more in the market)

Personal experience even I had the same issue on my web application and dotTrace traced the poorly written code for me

Comment: I used Ants Profiler and did not find any clue. I found the memory was occupied by a System.LocalDataStoreElemnt[] class. Do you know is this linq related?

Comment: @seanbun I have always used dotTrace because it gives you hotspot of every function call made based on the percentage it returned for a funtion, so refactor it to see in next run if its returns better number then previous. In your case it could be Linq so I would suggest is try to use a non-linq code and check for the difference in numbers, thats the best I can suggest

Answer (score 1):

> Exception thrown when there is not enough memory to continue execution
>   of a program.
>
> In order to view your message,  see the OutOfMemoryException
>   constructors.

Reasons :

1. you have an infinite loop.
2. You have lot of data, verify your queries sql when you load your context ans entities set.